# Running procedure to reset Password ORACLE error: ORA-01031: privilegios insuficientes

Tags: oracle

Buen día a todos, estoy tratando de ejecutar este procedimiento.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE /*noneditionable*/
PROCEDURE SYSTEM.prc_alter_password(usuario  VARCHAR2, passwd  varchar ) IS
  --cadena varchar2(1000);
BEGIN

  -- Verificacion= No debe ser usuario esquema!
  IF upper(usuario) IN
     ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'SYSMAN') THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('No esta permitido cambiar este password');
  ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER ' || usuario || ' ACCOUNT UNLOCK';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER ' || usuario || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || passwd;
    --execute immediate 'ALTER USER ' || usuario||' PASSWORD EXPIRE';
    dbms_output.put_line('Altered User: ' || usuario);
    dbms_output.put_line('New Password: ' || passwd);
  END IF;
  -- commit;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('error: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Y realizo el test con el siguiente bloque.

```
    begin
      -- Call the procedure
      prc_alter_password(usuario => :usuario,
                         passwd => :passwd);
end;
```

Pero tengo est error.
error: ORA-01031: privilegios insuficientes

Answer (score 0):

Funciona después de dar un grant.

```
grant alter user to system;
```